# About morphisms of $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $\alpha: C^{\infty}(M)\to \mathbb{R}.$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

Prove that for all morphisms of $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $\alpha: C^{\infty}(M)\to \mathbb{R}$ there is unique $x \in M$ such that  $\alpha(f)=ev_{x}(f)=f(x).$

Comment: This looks like you copied it out of an exercise list.

Comment: This is a very interesting, non-trivial  question and it is unfortunate that users who are in no way responsible for the OP's formulation will be deprived of an answer to it.

Comment: This is a problem in Milnor's book characteristic class, I no have idea of prove.

Comment: The proof of this fact can be found in the book "Smooth manifolds and Observables" by Jet Nestruev. It is the "7.2 Theorem". It's a very curious result since it tells us that the geometric space can be recovered from the algebra $C^\infty(M)$.